# Is there a way to generate a dtd and xsd from an existing xml file?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I have written an xml. I want to generate a dtd and xsd for it. Is there a tool i can use for the same instead of typing everything So that i can avoid mistakes? looking forward for some inputs/leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this online tool for small xml files
http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html

Comment: Also you can use http://xml.mherman.org/

Answer (score 4):

A DTD against which you can validate your document can easily be generated:

```
<!ELEMENT e (#PCDATA | e)* >
```

Or for XSD, a schema document containing only

```
<xsd:element name="e"/>
```

If that is not satisfactory, perhaps you forgot to say that you want the DTD to accept your XML document as valid.  In that case, I'd implement something like the following pseudo-code, in XSLT or XQuery

```
for each $gi in distinct-values($input/descendant-or-self::*/name())
return '<!ELEMENT ' || $gi || ' ANY >&#xA;'
```

For XSD, change the return statement to

```
return '<xsd:element name="{$gi}"/>'
```

If those are not satisfactory, perhaps you forgot to say what other constraints the document grammar should obey.

We can generate a grammar that captures the parent/child relations in the input (i.e. it allows any element E to be a child of element F if and only if some E element appears in the input as a child of an F element) with code like

```
for each $gi in distinct-values($input/descendant-or-self::*/name())
let $occurrences := $input/descendant-or-self::*[name() = $gi]
    $children := distinct-values($occurrences/*/name(),
    $mixed := some $t in $occurrences/child::text()
              satisfies normalize-space($t),
    $contentmodel0 := string-join(
                      (if ($mixed) then '#PCDATA' else (), $children),
                      ' | '
                      )
return '<!ELEMENT ' || $gi || ' ' 
       || '(' 
       || $contentmodel0
       || ')* >&#xA;'
```

I'll leave the equivalent XSD formulation as an exercise for the reader.

If it's not enough that the grammar capture the parent/child relations in the input, but you also want the sequence of children allowed for any element in the grammar to 'match' (in some sense) the examples in the input, then you have reached an interesting problem (worth a master's thesis or a dissertation not long ago):  for each instance of element E in your input, you have some finite number of sequences of children:  your task is to define a regular language that includes those sequences and captures the implicit patterns of the input clearly.  It should be obvious that much will depend on your definition of 'like' and of 'clearly'.

If your requirement is that a sequence of children be allowed in the grammar if and only if it's instantiated in the input, then the formulation of the content model for element E is simple, complicated for DTDs and XSD only by the determinism rule (known in XSD as the 'unique particle attribution rule', which is just a slightly less clear and more imposing way of saying 'determinism rule').  For any given set of sequences, there may be more than one possible formulation as a content model; choosing the simplest will require some measure of complexity for content models and some way of finding the simplest available formulation.

If you did this experiment with a sample HTML document, you might find that `ul` ends up with a content model like `(li, li, li, li, (li, li, li, li, li)?)` because the input had two lists, one with four items and one with nine. If you want your program to generate a 'simpler' or 'better' content model for lists, like `(li+)` or `(li*)`, then you want your grammar to allow not just the finite number of sequence children found in the input but also other sequences "like" them.  That is, you must find a suitable way to generalize from the inputs.  There are an infinite number of ways to do so (and even when the class of legal generalizations is constrained as tightly as anyone now knows how to do, there are still a very large number), and choosing the one that feels 'right' to a human is likely to be difficult for most software.

In sum:  There are an infinite number of document grammars that will accept your XML input as valid.  If they are not all equally useful for your purposes, then you need to constrain your problem more tightly in order for it to have a useful answer.

Further information is available in [this earlier Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578448/how-to-generate-dtd-from-xml), which you should have found if you had searched the site for answers before posting your question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @C. M. Sperberg-McQueen. I was just looking for a simple online tool. like xml.mherman.org.

Comment: +1 for showing how to generate a grammar *instead of **typing** everything*, which is what OP requested, in both senses of the word.  :-)